# JMS to MQ message publishing error: "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, tls1.2, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to connect to a SSL enabled MQ channel in order to place a message using JMS(within Spring boot app) . below are the connection factory properties set before sending the message. I'm getting the
following error when jms trying to put the message.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR')....
.....
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
```

** certificates are already installed at QM level. it seems jms client is not picking the root certificate from the specified location. the CA root certificate(myCAcertfile.cer) (self signed) was generated using runmqckm tool in IBM mq.

MQ channel information

```
   CHANNEL(KAU.CONN)                       CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2014-02-28)                     ALTTIME(17.28.55)
   CERTLABL( )                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)
   DESCR(Server-connection to windows host)
   DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)
   SSLPEER( )                              TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

JMS connection factory properties

```
            // Create a connection factory
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

            // Set the properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "Manual message publihser");
            cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "");
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "");


            System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false" );
            
            cf.setStringProperty("Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\mq-message-handler-1.0\\ssl\\myCAcertfile.cer");
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
```

Commands used to create CA's certificate

```
runmqckm -keydb -create -db myCA.kdb -type cms  -pw mycakeypassword -stash
runmqckm -cert -create -db myCA.kdb -type cms -label "myCAcertificate" -dn "CN=demmoCA,O=DemmoOrg,OU=DemmoDepartment,L=DemmoLocation,C=UK" -expire 1000 -size 1024
runmqckm -cert -extract -db myCA.kdb -type cms -label "myCAcertificate" -target myCAcertfile.cer -format ascii -stashed
```

then created the keystore for the client using above certificate using key tool

```
keytool -keystore kautstclient.jks -genkey -alias winclientcert -storepass clientpassword
keytool -import -keystore kautstclient.jks -file myCAcertfile.cer -alias theCARoot
```

30/02/2022 update > I have now added the certificates to the client side using below commands.

```
generating client side's CA to self sign the client's certificate
================================================================
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365


creating certificate request from the jks in order to signed by the above CA.
===========================================================================

 keytool -certreq -v -alias winclientcert -file kauclient.csr -keypass clientpassword -storepass clientpassword -keystore kautstclient.jks
 
signing the certificate requst(csr file) using the generated CA key 
==================================================
openssl x509 -req -in kauclient.csr -CA cert.pem -CAkey key.pem -CAcreateserial -out kauclientown.crt


 Import the the signed and then provided certificate  certificate into your keystore using the following command:
========================================================================================

keytool -import -v -alias kauclientowncert -file kauclientown.crt -keystore kautstclient.jks -keypass clientpassword -storepass clientpassword


adding the client's key signed root CA in to queue manager's key.db
=================================================================
runmqckm -cert -add -db  myqmgr.kdb -file cert.pem -label kauclientsignercertificate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` is not a connection factory property. You need to pass it as a Java system property. The value of the property needs to be either a JKS or PKCS12 file.

You can do this in two ways:

1. As a `-D` command line option:

   ```
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\mq-message-handler-1.0\ssl\myCAcertfile.jks
   ```
2. Using `System.setProperty`:

   ```
   System.setProperty(javax.net.ssl.trustStore, "D:\mq-message-handler-1.0\ssl\myCAcertfile.jks");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this, once I have Used the following, Started to get a different error now . ```Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: TrustAnchor with subject "CN=demmoCA, O=DemmoOrg, OU=DemmoDepartment, L=DemmoLocation, C=UK" is not a CA certificate ```

Comment: How did you create the CA cert? Please update your question with the commands you ran.

Comment: Some how I was able to find a solution for the above solution here(by adding  System.setProperty("jdk.security.allowNonCaAnchor","true"); ) ,https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-fix-error-javaxnetsslsslhandshakeexception-trustanchor-subject-cnpdca-opolicy-director-cus , but then again I got another gift mentioning  ```Exception in thread "HandshakeCompletedNotify-Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is deprecated and marked for removal. Use the getPeerCertificates() method instead.
 at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSession.getPeerCertificateChain(SSLSession.java:295) ```

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: in eclipse ```*** System properties:
java.runtime.version=17.0.1+12-LTS-39 ```

Comment: IBM MQ supports v7 and v8 at most supported versions.   At the latest 9.2.4 it supports v8, v11, and v17. Which MQ version are you using?

Comment: I will try changing the jdk. let know the status .. thanks for your comments!! much appreciated

Comment: MQ version is  9.2.0.0

Comment: I have configured the eclipse to use jdk1.8.0_202 and now I'm getting the following error ```Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=KAU.CONN]
 at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment(RemoteConnection.java:4464)``` In Qmanager log it says The conversation cannot begin because a certificate has not been supplied by the remote partner. then I have made SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) for the channel, and it worked. does that mean the all my SSL configs hasn't been used?

Comment: You only copied the public key to the client.   If you want REQUIRED you need to generate a cert for the client also.  With OPTIONAL it is still TLS  encrypted.

Comment: I have now added the certificates to the client side using the updated commands in the question. but still the MQ logs says ```The conversation cannot begin because a certificate has not been supplied by
the remote partner.
```

Comment: The queue manager should have its own private key and chain as well as the chain of the client's private key.   The client should have its own private key and chain as well as the chain of the queue manager's private key.   Is this the case?